# Do browsers optimize setAttribute() and similar when a value is already set?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, reflow

I often run a conditional to make sure a value has changed before updating the DOM, ex:

```js
const startSize = 10

function updateAttribute(newSize){
  if (newSize === startSize) return
  document.body.setAttribute('data-size', newSize)
}

function updateStyle(newSize){
  if (newSize === startSize) return
  document.body.style.setProperty('--my-size', newSize)
}
```

Is this an over-optimization?  Does the browser already run this check and only apply the new value if it's different from the old?

Comment: Checking the attribute and assigning the attribute are about the same cost, so doing the check would make things *more* expensive whenever the value changes.

Comment: You have `.setAttribute` twice.

Comment: I think what you really want to ask is if it optimizes out  re-rendering if nothing has changed that affects the display.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective @Barmar – between checking for changed value or if rerender is needed, it seems like the browser _should_ have enough checks in place.  Per your first comment my optimization is probably negligible at best.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Barmar why would getting the value have the same cost as setting it? Most attribute setters start huge machinery behind. While the getter only has to return the previously set value.

Comment: @Kaiido I wasn't thinking of attributes that have side effects related to them. It wasn't until my third comment that I realized that this is what concerned you.

Comment: Then what attributes were you thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an element's attribute almost always have (observable) side effects. And these side effects must kick in even when they're set to their current value.

This is highly visible for instance with the `<canvas>` element, where setting either its `width` or `height` will reset its buffer.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(50, 50, 80, 80);
setTimeout(() => {
  canvas.setAttribute("width", canvas.getAttribute("width"));
}, 3000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But also with media elements where setting their `src` or alike attributes will load the resource again, possibly triggering a full re-fetch if the resource isn't cached:

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
setTimeout(() => {
  img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("src"));
}, 3000);
```

```html
<img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif >
```

And even with *data-* attributes, where we could have thought there wouldn't be any side effects, this is still observable and browsers can't really optimize it out:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div");
setTimeout(() => {
  el.setAttribute("data-foo", el.getAttribute("data-foo"));
}, 3000);
const observer = new MutationObserver((recs) => recs.forEach((r) => console.log("attribute %s did change", r.attributeName)));
observer.observe(el, { attributes: true });
```

```html
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

Now, each attribute's side effect will have different cost, so it's up to you to determine if that cost is worth the check or not (e.g, in my `<canvas>` it's definitely worth it, but in your *data-* attribute case, it's less obvious, if you don't have an active observer you can almost ignore it.

---

Regarding the CSSOM, the browser will most likely optimize it.
Apart from through your browser's dev-tools a "no-change update" isn't really observable there. So your `.style.setProperty()` case corresponds to a simple *data-* attribute change.